# How to send KeyStroke in selenium to browser window (without locator)

Tags: java, selenium, keystroke

Can i send KeyStroke in Selenium in Java without using a locator?

I want to send KeyStroke to WebBrowser itself, because I don't know element (and its locator), to whom I must send KeyStroke to perform action, which I want. But I know, that action performing correctly, when I manually select browser as active window and just press 'Enter' on the keyboard without selecting any element on the page.

I tried this code

```
SeleniumSession.keyPressNative(Integer.toString(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER));
```

but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about sending it to the HTML element - ie find element by xpath `"/html"` and sendKeys() to it?

Comment: Trying this just close selenium session with error "Element not found". But i tried SeleniumSession.keyPress("//", "\\113"); and it did nothing

Comment: "//" is the locator for all elements, so you sent the keystroke to the first element of the page, whatever that is (probably <HEAD>).  Not likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try "//body", but I'm not sure it will work in the Selenium RC API.  This is one of the things that Selenium 2.x's WebDriver API was designed to make work well.